# Time-based rotation script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which retrieves the next value of the constant "rotation" every 30 minutes starting from a specific starting value and time.

The script displays only the current value and the following three upcoming values.

Here is the script and the corresponding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7zrfwgj/2/):

```
if ($('[id^=test]').length) {

    function addHours(date, hours) {
        var copy = new Date(date);
        copy.setTime(copy.getTime() + (hours * 30 * 30 * 1000));
        return copy;
    }

    function next(value) {
        return {
            index: (value.index + 1) % rotation.length,
            date: addHours(value.date, 2),
        };
    }

    const known = { id: 193210, ts: "2023-06-14T07:30:00Z" };
    const rotation = [
        { id: 193210, name: "Pfliep " },
        { id: 186827, name: "Magmaton" },
        { id: 193251, name: "Schroffi" },
        { id: 193227, name: "Ronsak der Dezimierer" },
        { id: 193240, name: "Flussläufer Tamopo" },
        { id: 193132, name: "Amethyzar der Glitzernde" },
        { id: 193234, name: "Eldoren der Wiedergeborene" },
        { id: 193149, name: "Skag der Werfer" },
        { id: 193173, name: "Mikrin der tobenden Winde" },
    ];

const now33 = new Date();
const now2 = addHours(now33, + 6);
const now3 = addHours(now33, - 2);
const end = addHours(now33, rotation.length * 2);

    var cur = {
        index: rotation.findIndex(li => li.id == known.id),
        date: Date.parse(known.ts),
    };

while (cur.date < now3)

    cur = next(cur);

    const out = document.getElementById("test");

    while (cur.date < end && cur.date < now2 && cur.date > now3) {

        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = 'test';

        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.textContent = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
        link.href = 'dadada';
        link.class = 'dadada';

        li.innerText = `${rotation[cur.index].name} (${cur.date.toLocaleString()})`;

        var id = `${rotation[cur.index].id}`;
        var title2 = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
        var link = "https://de.wowhead.com/npc=";
        var ClassName = "weeklytext";
        var ClassName2 = "weeklytext2";
        var ClassName3 = "peinigertime";
    
        var options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
        var date33 = `${ cur.date.toLocaleString('en-GB', options)}`;


        $("<li class=\"" + ClassName2 + "\"><div class=\"" + ClassName3 + "\"> " + date33 + "</div> <a class=\"" + ClassName  +"\" href=\"" + link + + id +"\">" + title2  +"</a></li>").appendTo(out);
        cur = next(cur);

    }
}
```

Now I want to add an exception. When the script reaches the value with the id "193234" the next value should appear after one hour, instead of the  30 minutes.

Something like:

```
if (next(cur)["index"] == "7") {
    function addHours(date, hours) {
        var copy = new Date(date);
        copy.setTime(copy.getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        return copy;
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to implement it correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? The time is hardcoded so that Eldoren is the first

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <script>
        $(function () {
          if ($("[id^=test]").length) {
            function addHours(date, hours) {
              var copy = new Date(date);
              copy.setTime(copy.getTime() + hours * 30 * 30 * 1000);
              return copy;
            }
    
            function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
              return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes * 60000);
            }
    
            function next(value) {
              return {
                index: (value.index + 1) % rotation.length,
                date: addHours(value.date, 2),
              };
            }
    
            const known = { id: 193210, ts: "2023-06-14T07:30:00Z" };
            const rotation = [
              { id: 193210, name: "Pfliep " },
              { id: 186827, name: "Magmaton" },
              { id: 193251, name: "Schroffi" },
              { id: 193227, name: "Ronsak der Dezimierer" },
              { id: 193240, name: "Flussläufer Tamopo" },
              { id: 193132, name: "Amethyzar der Glitzernde" },
              { id: 193234, name: "Eldoren der Wiedergeborene" },
              { id: 193149, name: "Skag der Werfer" },
              { id: 193173, name: "Mikrin der tobenden Winde" },
            ];
    
            const now33 = new Date("2023-06-17 07:30:01"); // just to Eldoren be the first, change back to new Date();
            const now2 = addHours(now33, +6);
            const now3 = addHours(now33, -2);
            const end = addHours(now33, rotation.length * 2);
    
            var cur = {
              index: rotation.findIndex((li) => li.id == known.id),
              date: Date.parse(known.ts),
            };
    
            while (cur.date < now3) {
              cur = next(cur);
            }
    
            const out = document.getElementById("test");
    
            let increaseMinutes = 0;
    
            while (cur.date < end && cur.date < now2 && cur.date > now3) {
              const li = document.createElement("li");
              li.className = "test";
    
              var link = document.createElement("a");
              link.textContent = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
              link.href = "dadada";
              link.class = "dadada";
    
              li.innerText = `${rotation[cur.index].name} (${cur.date.toLocaleString()})`;
    
              var id = `${rotation[cur.index].id}`;
              var title2 = `${rotation[cur.index].name}`;
              var link = "https://de.wowhead.com/npc=";
              var ClassName = "weeklytext";
              var ClassName2 = "weeklytext2";
              var ClassName3 = "peinigertime";
    
              var options = { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric" };
    
              var date33 = `${addMinutes(cur.date, increaseMinutes).toLocaleString("en-GB", options)}`;
    
              if (id == 193234) {
                increaseMinutes = 30;
              } else if (increaseMinutes > 0) {
                increaseMinutes += 30;
              }
    
              $(
                '<li class="' +
                  ClassName2 +
                  '"><div class="' +
                  ClassName3 +
                  '"> ' +
                  date33 +
                  '</div> <a class="' +
                  ClassName +
                  '" href="' +
                  link +
                  +id +
                  '">' +
                  title2 +
                  "</a></li>"
              ).appendTo(out);
              cur = next(cur);
            }
          }
        });
      </script>
    
      <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried your code, but there seems to be a problem in the rotation. The rotation-sequence doesn't seem to work correctly.

For easier checking I've updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6ckz2r1/3/). 


`const known = { id: 193210, ts: "2023-06-17T22:30:00Z" };`

Comment: Can you try to elaborate more why the rotation is incorrect? And why did you change the known const?

Comment: From the const "known" the rotation should start and always get the next value after 30 minutes. The exception is when the rotation is reaching the id "193234" then the next value should come after 1 hour (instead of 30 minutes).

If you check the rotation, like the values should appear, it's the wrong sequence. I've changed the known const to make the testing easier. For example: At 3 o'clock AM the value should be "id: 193173", not the id: "193132".

Comment: It works now as expected. I had a misconception. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For easy checking, this code just output the li element every 1 second and only when the ID is "193234" in 2 seconds.

```
const rotation = [
  { id: 193210, name: "Pfliep " },
  { id: 186827, name: "Magmaton" },
  { id: 193251, name: "Schroffi" },
  { id: 193227, name: "Ronsak der Dezimierer" },
  { id: 193240, name: "Flussläufer Tamopo" },
  { id: 193132, name: "Amethyzar der Glitzernde" },
  { id: 193234, name: "Eldoren der Wiedergeborene" },
  { id: 193149, name: "Skag der Werfer" },
  { id: 193173, name: "Mikrin der tobenden Winde" },
];
var currentIndex = 0;

function next(index) {
    const nextItem = rotation[index];
    var delay = 1 * 1000;
    if (nextItem.id == "193234") {
      delay = 2 * 1000;
    }
    setTimeout(update, delay);
}

function update() {
  const item = rotation[currentIndex];
  const html = "<li>" + item.id + ": " + item.name + "</li>";
  $(html).appendTo("#test");
  currentIndex++;
  if (currentIndex >= rotation.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  // TODO Call only if condition is met
  next(currentIndex);
}

$(function() {
  if ($("[id^=test]").length) {
    next(currentIndex);
  }
});
```

Comment: You mean like that? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4e680vf5/). Sadly I don't see any results.

Comment: I've revised and simplified the whole code.
Culd you try this and if it works well, please modify the output content to suit your purpose.